# Android studio, set checkbox value from checked to unchecked, in the other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox, logout

I have a "save" checkbox in the login activity. If the user check it, next time, when the application going to start , skip the login activity. Although, If User wants to logout, the checkbox in the login activity going to set unchecked. This problem, what I can't solve.

Login Activity the saveing part:

```
saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);
    if (saveLogin == true) {
        etEmail.setText(loginPreferences.getString("email", ""));
        etPassword.setText(loginPreferences.getString("password", ""));
        saveLoginCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    //    editor.putBoolean("checked", true);

     /*   editor.putString("email", "etEmail"); // Storing string
        editor.putString("password", "etPassword"); // Storing string*/

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etEmail.getWindowToken(), 0);

        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        if (saveLoginCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("email", email);
            loginPrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        } else {
            loginPrefsEditor.clear();
            loginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }

        Backendless.UserService.login(email, password, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessUser>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(BackendlessUser response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sikeres bejelentlezés",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoryActivity.class);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(loginIntent);



            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sikertelen bejelentlezés",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And the User activity.... This part, where is a logout button:

```
 bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Backendless.UserService.logout(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(Void response) {


                        finish();

                        Intent logoutIntent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(logoutIntent);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nem sikerült kijelentkezni!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by shared preferences.. if user logged in just store the value in the sharedpreference let say

```
 Sp.putString("userinfo","loggedin");
   Sp.commit();
```

and whenever you comeback just check the preference if it has the value loggedin then jus go to your main activity.else show login activity

```
  String data =SpEditor.getString("userinfo", null);
   If(data!= null){
   goto main}
  Else goto login
```

Hopeit helps!!

Comment: Thank you! Althought , this function is going well, my main problem is logout, or rather the checkbox set to unchecked from checked, if user wants to logout. And these are not in same activity, so I think this solotuin is also with sharedpreferences, but i dont know how :((

Comment: Same function before set jus check the shared preference value if u got the value set it to checked else set it to unchecked

Comment: I apologize,because I misunderstood. When te user going to login , the checkbox didn't change so, automatically going to the main menu. Indeed to change the checkbox value to unchecked.

Comment: 1.show thelogin screen with checkbox unchecked.. if user checked the box then while login put ur values in the sp. Else dont do it.  And whenever user opens app jus get the sp values if u get the values then show the main activity else show the login screen